# подскажите способ хранения в redis данных list

Tags: python, redis

есть данные в формате list на каждые 5 минут графика bitcoin. 105 тысяч записей получается за год.

```
list = ['bitcoin', timestamps, 'цена открытия','цена закрытия']
```

какой вид записи в redis лучше использовать, чтобы потом данные через цикл анализировать?

Есть идея **hmset**, храним и через цикл достаем по timestamps

```
hmset bitcoin_5min timestamps ['цена открытия','цена закрытия']
```

Или есть более изящное решение?